# Token refreshing with Retrofit and Interceptor for multiple requests in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, authentication, retrofit, interceptor

How to handle token refresh for multiple requests in Interceptor?

I'm implementing token refresh functionality in my Android app using an AuthInterceptor in Retrofit. The code provided works well for a single request, but I'm encountering issues when multiple requests are made simultaneously.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
class AuthInterceptor(private val authorizationRepository: AuthorizationRepository) : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {

        val originalRequest = chain.request()

        val userIsNotAuthorize = runBlocking { !authorizationRepository.userIsAuthorize().first() }

        if (userIsNotAuthorize) {
            return chain.proceed(originalRequest)
        }

        val accessToken = authorizationRepository.getAccessToken()

        val tokenHasExpired = authorizationRepository.tokenHasExpired()

        return if (tokenHasExpired) {
            chain.proceedDeletingTokenOnError(
                originalRequest.newBuilder()
                    .addHeaders(accessToken)
                    .build()
            )
        } else {
            val refreshTokenRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                .post("".toRequestBody("application/json".toMediaType()))
                .url(BuildConfig.BASE_URL + "/v1/user/refresh")
                .addHeaders(accessToken)
                .build()

            val refreshResponse = chain.proceedDeletingTokenOnError(refreshTokenRequest)

            refreshResponse.use {
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    val refreshedToken = Gson().fromJson(
                        it.body?.string(),
                        AuthorizedUserDto::class.java
                    )
                    authorizationRepository.setAccessToken(
                        refreshedToken.items.token,
                        refreshedToken.items.expiredAt
                    )
                    val newCall = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                        .addHeaders(refreshedToken.items.token)
                        .build()
                    chain.proceedDeletingTokenOnError(newCall)
                } else {
                    chain.proceedDeletingTokenOnError(originalRequest)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private inline fun Request.Builder.addHeaders(token: String) =
        this.apply { header("Authorization", "Bearer $token") }

    private fun Interceptor.Chain.proceedDeletingTokenOnError(request: Request): Response {
        val response = proceed(request)
        if (response.code == 401) {
            runBlocking { authorizationRepository.changeUserState(UserState.NotAuthorized) }
        }
        return response
    }
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that when multiple requests are made and the token has expired, the interceptor proceeds with token refresh for each request individually. As a result, the refresh token endpoint may be called multiple times, causing the token to become invalid.

I've tried debugging my app and noticed that the /v1/user/refresh request can be triggered multiple times. I'm wondering if there is a better solution to handle token refresh for multiple requests simultaneously. Any suggestions or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: check out my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77206302/11671900

Answer (score 1):

You could handle multiple requests in interceptor using locks, find below code with comments using `ReentrantLock`

```
class AuthInterceptor(private val authorizationRepository: AuthorizationRepository) : Interceptor {

    //Create a lock object, assuming you are same instance of interceptor for all requests or create a static lock
    private val reentrantLock = ReentrantLock(true)

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {

        val originalRequest = chain.request()
        val userIsNotAuthorize = runBlocking { !authorizationRepository.userIsAuthorize().first() }
        if (userIsNotAuthorize) {
            return chain.proceed(originalRequest)
        }

        val accessToken = authorizationRepository.getAccessToken()
        val tokenHasExpired = authorizationRepository.tokenHasExpired()

        return if (tokenHasExpired) {
            chain.proceedDeletingTokenOnError(
                originalRequest.newBuilder()
                    .addHeaders(accessToken)
                    .build()
            )
        } else {
            //lock before refreshing
            reentrantLock.lock()
            //verify if previous request already updated the token while entering the locked block
            val recentAccessToken = authorizationRepository.getAccessToken()
            val recentTokenHasExpired = authorizationRepository.tokenHasExpired()
            if(recentTokenHasExpired) {
                return chain.proceed(
                    originalRequest.newBuilder()
                    .addHeaders(accessToken)
                    .build())
            }
            //if not refreshed refresh inside lock
                val refreshTokenRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                    .post("".toRequestBody("application/json".toMediaType()))
                    .url(BuildConfig.BASE_URL + "/v1/user/refresh")
                    .addHeaders(accessToken)
                    .build()
                val refreshResponse = chain.proceedDeletingTokenOnError(refreshTokenRequest)

                refreshResponse.use {
                    if (it.isSuccessful) {
                        val refreshedToken = Gson().fromJson(
                            it.body?.string(),
                            AuthorizedUserDto::class.java
                        )
                        authorizationRepository.setAccessToken(
                            refreshedToken.items.token,
                            refreshedToken.items.expiredAt
                        )
                        val newCall = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                            .addHeaders(refreshedToken.items.token)
                            .build()
                        chain.proceedDeletingTokenOnError(newCall)
                    } else {
                        chain.proceedDeletingTokenOnError(originalRequest)
                    }
                }
                // unlock after refreshing token, so next request 
                // in queue waiting for lock would proceed with updated token
                reentrantLock.unlock()
        }
    }

    private inline fun Request.Builder.addHeaders(token: String) =
        this.apply { header("Authorization", "Bearer $token") }

    private fun Interceptor.Chain.proceedDeletingTokenOnError(request: Request): Response {
        val response = proceed(request)
        if (response.code == 401) {
            runBlocking { authorizationRepository.changeUserState(UserState.NotAuthorized) }
        }
        return response
    }
}
```